# Jquery Datatable is not becoming responsive

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a jquery Datatable implemented on bootstrap theme which is supossed to be responsive but its not.Here is my HTML..

```
<div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" id="bttable">
                <tfoot>
                    <tr></tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
```

and here is my jquery..

```
 dt = $("#bttable").dataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "paging": false,
            "responsive": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "columns": [
                { "title": "<input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'>", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px", },
                { "title": "<a href='#' class='btn btn-xs' title='Edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#responsive' onclick='edit()'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px" },
                { "title": "FirstName", "width": "50px" },
                { "title": "LastName" },
                { "title": "Contact Number" },
                { "title": "Email ID" }
            ]
        });
```

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/56n6wwd8/

Please help me to make this datatable responsive..Thanks..

Comment: Your code works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/56n6wwd8/3/. Don't forget to include Responsive extension, see [Download Builder](http://datatables.net/download/index).

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" id="bttable">
            <tfoot>
                <tr></tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: R u there ? Any help on the problem ?

Comment: Imran actually i am very new to programming so donno how to create a fiddle correctly..Please improve fiddle and help me ..